# Set Logstash output index in 24/h time format

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

How to set the Logstash output for index creation in 24 hours format?

`%{+YYYY.MM.dd.hh}`

this will create every hour an index, but not in 24 hours format. any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using capital `HH`, i.e. `YYYY.MM.dd.HH`.

Small `hh` will generate data in range 1-12 with am/pm, while `HH` will be in 24 hour range.

Comment: ok will change the configuration and update here for any outcomes..thx